# recommendations register state doesn't completely respect locale given

Tags: facebook, localization

When I include an iframe with url:
http://www.facebook.com/plugins/recommendations.php?locale=nl_NL&site=http%3A%2F%2Fmydomain.com&width=294&height=280&header=true&colorscheme=light

It displays the text:

> Create an account or "Meld je aan" to see what your friends are recommending.

with mixed languages. Other texts in other variants of recommendations are in the correct locale, only this text is wrong.

This view of the plugin is only shown when the user on the current browser hasn't ever logged in (or deleted cookies).

Can I provide the correct translation to facebook, how should I approach this?